# box-shadow on img in CSS

Tags: image, css

Is it possible to add a shadow to the img tag in CSS, I tried and it doesn't seems to work. Am I correct or my code is just messed up

CSS

```
.image_carousel img {
  padding-right: 14px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #ccc;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #ccc;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="image_carousel"><img src="../imgs/image.jpg" width="800" height="600" alt=""/></div>
```

Comment: Why do the width and height in the HTML differ from those in the CSS? Are you sure the shadow isn't just off-screen or something?

Comment: The code is almost right (M. Cypher is right about img size), but what is your browser? Your code should be supported (if I do not mistaken) by IE 9+, latest versions of Chrome, Opera 10.50+, Firefox 3.5+, Safari 3.1+.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

looks like you can:

```css
.image_carousel img {
  margin-right: 14px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #ccc;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_carousel"><img src="//placehold.it/300/f80/fff" alt=""/></div>
```

Comment: But not inset (-webkit-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 1px #ccc;)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-box-shadow), `box-shadow` applies to all elements. But this is the CSS3 spec, and so only a handful of browsers will support it for now:

- IE9
- FF4
- Opera 10.5
- Safari 3
- Chrome 1

are the ones that come to mind now

Answer (score 0):

```
img.carousel {box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #ccc;} /*works fine 

<img src="whatever.png" class="carousel">
```

or try for fun

```
img.carousel {border:1px solid #ccc;}

img.carousel:hover {box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #ccc;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
img {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);
}
</style>
<img src="http://jadide.ir/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/2.jpg" alt=""/>
```