# Is it possible to add image as box shadow with css?

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

Is it possible to add image as box shadow, for example to put image with dots instead of standard shadow?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOJGh.png

or somehow to replace shadow from picture with dots?

to get effect like this on picture down here

http://prntscr.com/fvjnht

Comment: Possible duplicate of [box-shadow on img in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930991/box-shadow-on-img-in-css)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. He doesn't want a box sahdow for an image, he wants an image as a box shadow.

Answer (score 3):

Did you want something like this? It's not exactly `box-shadow`, but it imitates it. 
You can set whatever image you like as a `background` for `.image::after`.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.contain {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.image{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/200x200);
}
.image::after {
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333, red);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is exactly what you are looking for:

```css
body {
        background: black;
    }
    
    #logo {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    #logo::after {
        content: "";
        background: url("https://rfclipart.com/image/big/3f-a9-1a/red-dotted-halftone-background-Download-Royalty-free-Vector-File-EPS-183199.jpg");
        opacity: 0.4;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 50%;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    
    img {
        width: 90%;
        height: 90%;
        padding: 5%;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #ccc;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #ccc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #ccc;
    }
```

```html
<div id="logo">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/colorful-long-
    shadow/256/User-icon.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6931044/6203984)?

```css
.image_carousel img {
  margin-right: 14px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #ccc;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_carousel"><img src="//placehold.it/300/f80/fff" alt=""/></div>
```

Credit goes to [Joseph Marikle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854246/joseph-marikle).

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
span {
  border: 2px dotted red;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span class="dotted-border"><img src="http://placehold.it/200"/></span>
```